# Do people still have to write thesis after finishing their master/phd?

Tags: publications, phd, thesis, masters, online-publication

I know that the thesis is needed when doing their master.
But do people still need to write a thesis when doing research as a past-time?

What if they just want to publish an article but not thesis?

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking about. Theses are only written as part of the requirements of a degree (essentially by definition), so why would one write one in other situations?

Comment: So thesis is not actually required for other situations?

Comment: Why would it be? Who would require it?

Comment: Thesis is only required to earn an academic degree. If you already have a degree, or are doing research without one, you would not produce a paper, not a(nother) thesis. Many grad students "double dip", using the same work for both a thesis (to get the master's or PhD) and an article.

Comment: What _other situations_? This is so vague it could mean job application or buying groceries. Please clarify what exactly you mean, what's the context of your question.

Answer (score 6):

No, people don't have to write theses after the Masters/PhD. The thesis is a formal requirement for those degrees, but after that, it's just not necessary anymore.

Actual research papers, though ... those are effectively "compulsory".

Comment: The are "compulsory" only if you want a career in academia. Otherwise not at all.

Comment: ...except for [habilitation theses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habilitation), which are post-doctoral theses required for certain academic positions in several (mostly European) countries.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure in which academic system the other answerer works, but yes, theses are actually required after the PhD sometimes. A categorical answer like this makes little sense and would probably benefit from a broadened point of view. For example, the habilitation, which one obtains after the PhD, requires a thesis in many countries (Germany, France...).

However they are not required to publish articles. Even students who have never written a thesis can publish articles, if their research is good enough.